# How run Jquery code after form submission

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, forms, form-submit

Hey everyone I have a html form and I want to run JQuery code after successfully form submission, I used Laravel, what I have to do??

Comment: You have to show us some code so we can help

Comment: The page the form is in is gone when form submits unless you are submitting it with ajax. Please be a lot more specific. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using ajax you can use `preventDefault()` so the form doesn't get submitted 'traditionally'. After the ajax is successful, you can then put your logic in the success function.

e.g.

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
       method: 'POST' //assume its a post method
       url: '{{url(cats)}}', //the route endpoint
       data: data //data to be sent
       success: function(response) { 
         // logic goes here, it means form submission is successful
       },
       error: function(e){
         // error has occured
         console.log(e)
       }
   });
});
```

**Make sure in your form element** set action to hashtag and remove method. So it doesn't get executed traditionally.

e.g.

```
<form action="#">
```

**Why use this approach?**

If you send form traditionally, it will refresh the page, which means your client side JS will not be executed! Ajax is for async HTTP request.

**Don't forget**

If you're using **HTTP methods** other than **GET**, add the CSRF TOKEN to headers. This is how you set it up before ajax calls.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> //add to head section 

 //js - before your ajax function, put in script section
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});
```

Good luck!

---

Reference:

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf